# python datetime swapping day month

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date time object that looks like:

```
2015-31-12 00:34:00
```

where the second element (31) represents the day and the third element (12) represents the month. How do I swap day and month so that the date looks like:

```
2015-12-31 00:34:00
```

Comment: Do you mean an actual `datetime` object? Have you tried `strftime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.strftime).

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
formatted_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 4):

You'd [parse the string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) into a [`datetime` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) then [format it again](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) back to a string:

```
from datetime import datetime

result = datetime.strptime(inputstring, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> inputstring = '2015-31-12 00:34:00'
>>> datetime.strptime(inputstring, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2015-12-31 00:34:00'
```

So the `datetime.strptime()` parses the string given a pattern, where you specify that the order is year-day-month, and `datetime.strftime()` formats it back to a string, with the day and month positions swapped.